# Asynchronous check of Azure Queues using message pump

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

In my application, I am wanting to check the main queue and the dead letter queue using the message pump that is setup. The problem I am running into is the threading on the default implementation.

I'm not sure how to get both of these to run at the same time

This is the default implementation of the message pump from Azure

```
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
                {

                }, new OnMessageOptions { AutoComplete = false});
            CompletedEvent.WaitOne()
```

The waitone method waits until the the manualResetEvent set method is called.
I'm not sure what is setting the method, I guess it's something going on behind the scenes of the onmessage process.

What's happening now, is the onmessage method runs and it hits the waitone process and sits there until another message comes in, which is the supposed to happen, but how would I get two of these running at the same time?

Comment: You should consider using an Azure Web Job.  It is a nice abstraction for coupling a job with a queue that triggers that job. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have a console app that runs your code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var completedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ...
        var mainQueue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString", "MyQueueName");

        mainQueue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
        {

        }, new OnMessageOptions { AutoComplete = false });

        completedEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

If you remove the `completedEvent.WaitOne();` you console app will exit immediately. This line ensure that your application is not going to exit. You could have write a `while(true) {}` instead (not recommended but this is another topic).

The message pump does not block the current: This is why you need to block the thread (in the case of a console app, azure webjob, azure worker role) for your application not to exit. If you implement this code into a windows service or inside a web app you don't have to block the main thread because there are other mechanisms to keep your application running.

When a new message arrives, the message pump spins up a new thread to execute the code inside the `OnMessage` block.

So if you want to listen to both main queue and dead letter queue, you can do something like that :

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var completedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ...
        var mainQueue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString", "MyQueueName");
        var deadLetterQueue = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString", QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath("MyQueueName"));

        mainQueue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
        {

        }, new OnMessageOptions { AutoComplete = false });

        deadLetterQueue.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
        {

        }, new OnMessageOptions { AutoComplete = false });

        completedEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: ah that makes sense, I had a misunderstanding of the use of the waitone method call. 

This worked perfectly thank you

Comment: May be in your context, you don't need to have to block the main thread ? Is your code running inside a worker role ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not following your question, but what you've got here is a callback registered with OnMessage API and continuation of your main program if a single message was received. Why would you do WaitOne outside of the callback? Callback is intended to run in a tight loop in the background and receive your messages.

If you only want to receive one or two messages, perhaps using [`QueueClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.aspx) (or similar) is a better option?